# os.Chdir("/tmp") works abnormally in Go

Tags: go, chdir

I used Macbook.
I tried to use `os.Chdir("/tmp")` but the outcome was `/private/tmp`. Following is my code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  s, _ := os.Getwd()
  fmt.Println(s)

  if err := os.Chdir("/tmp"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  s, _ = os.Getwd()
  fmt.Println(s)

}
```

And the output is:

```
➜  test   go run main.go
/Users/willy/test
/private/tmp
```

Why?

Comment: Is `/tmp` a symbolic link to `/private/tmp`? What does `ls -ld /tmp` say?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but if you're trying to switch to the default temporary directory use `os.TempDir()` instead of specifying the directory yourself. This will be more portable across different systems and configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As chown in this [Apple thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4903601?tstart=0)

> On OS X, `/tmp` is an alias for `/private/tmp`.

```
$ ls -ale / | grep -i tmp

lrwxr-xr-x@    1 root  wheel        11 Aug 30  2009 tmp -> private/tmp

$
```

And a [golang `syscall.Chdir()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a8c6c4837c17ab4ec3ba78e40b9a72dc70d9cf5a/src/os/file.go#L223-L226) would follow that symlink.
So the final path is expected on a Mac OS platform.